# Cómo enviar una lista de objetos de Adaptar a Activity

Tags: java, android

**Buenas tardes, estoy trabajando con Android y java  tengo dos tablas clientes y pedidos en una de las pantallas estoy listando  en un CardView  el nombre del cliente  y  el nro. De pedidos por cliente. Quiero que al seleccionar la tarjeta(CardView) me envíe a otra actividad la lista de pedidos.**

Este es mi Adapter

```
public class ClienteWithPedidoAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ClienteWithPedidoAdapter.ClienteWithPedidoViewHolder> {
    List<ClientesWithPedidos> lista;
    List<Pedidos> listpedidos;
    sendData listener;
    public interface  sendData{
        void sendInfo(List<Pedidos> list);
    }
    public ClienteWithPedidoAdapter(sendData listener){
        this.listener=listener;
    }
    public ClienteWithPedidoAdapter(){
    }
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        if (lista!=null){
            return lista.size();
        }else{
            return 0;
        }
    }
    public void setLista(List<ClientesWithPedidos> clientesWithPedidos){
        lista=clientesWithPedidos;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
    public class ClienteWithPedidoViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        TextView cliente;
        TextView numpedi;
        public ClienteWithPedidoViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            cliente=itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtClientePedidoCliente);
            numpedi=itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtClientePedidoNumPedi);
            itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    listpedidos=lista.get(getLayoutPosition()).pedidosList;
                    listener.sendInfo(listpedidos);
                }
            });
```

Mi Actividad donde quiero recibir.

```
public class DetallePedidosActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements ClienteWithPedidoAdapter.sendData {
     public List<Pedidos> listita;
     ClienteWithPedidoAdapter clienteWithPedidoAdapter;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_detalle_pedidos);
        clienteWithPedidoAdapter=new ClienteWithPedidoAdapter(this);
    }
    @Override
    public void sendInfo(List<Pedidos> list) {
        listita=list;
        listita.size();
    }
}
```

Me sale este error.

```
 Process: com.example.myaplication, PID: 29649
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'void com.example.myaplication.adapter.ClienteWithPedidoAdapter$sendData.sendInfo(java.util.List)' on a null object reference
```

Answer (score 0):

Creo que el error es en que al hacer click en el item, se está intentando acceder a pedidosList: lista.get(getLayoutPosition()).pedidosList; pero la lista nunca ha sido seteada, por lo que su valor es null –